# Can I use the red 5 to move someone out of their safety zone?

Tags: sorry

I'm playing *Sorry! The Disney Edition*. If I am the red player, and I get a red 5 card (lets people move opponents backwards 5). Can I move someone out of their safety?

[image]

Comment: The rules for this game are terrible.  If I were to play this game with one of my groups we would allow this action because they need to follow the rules to the letter.  The other group I play with, would honour the spirit of the "Safey" zone to mean that it was "safe from effects".  Either way is perfectly fine as long as you are all following the same rules.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** According to the fifth page in the [official rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry_Disney_Edition.pdf) for *Sorry! The Disney Edition*, you can move out of the Safety Zone with a backwards move card. The rules also state that you can use backward move cards on other players when the card says you can. Therefore, it is heavily implied, if not explicitly said, that a backwards move card *can* be used to move a player's piece from their Safety Zone back onto the board.

According to the fifth page of the rules:

> "Safety Zone: Only you may enter your SAFETY ZONE. You cannot enter the SAFETY ZONE by a backward move; however, you may move backward out of the SAFETY ZONE and, on later turns, move back in as cards allow."

A piece may not move out of its Home position for any reason, also according to the fifth page in the rules.

Comment: The exact quote if you wish to incorperate it into your answer: "Safety Zone:
Only you may enter your SAFETY ZONE. You cannot enter the SAFETY ZONE by a backward move; however, you may move backward out of the SAFETY ZONE and, on later turns, move back in as cards allow."

Comment: Np, I have a handy little screenshot tool that converts pictures of text into copy/pasteable text, very convenient I find.